# Dynamic page refresh JavaScript/PHP or 'Pusher.com'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, pusher

I'm looking for a solution to be able to dynamically force a refresh on my web page to all my current viewers. It would be easiest if this was done through php however I'm open to suggestions.

I have done some research and have found a possible solution (pusher.com) however I'm not sure how to execute this. Here is my code below:

JavaScript on my web page added to `document.ready` jQuery':

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxx');
var refreshChannel = pusher.subscribe('refreshing');
refreshChannel.bind('refresh-event', function() {
location.reload(true);
});
```

Here is my php code from their official documentation:

```
<?php
 require('Pusher.php');
 $options = array(
 'cluster' => 'eu',
 'encrypted' => true
 );
 $pusher = new Pusher(
'xxx',
'xxx',
'xxx',
 $options);

 $data['message'] = 'hello world';
 $pusher->trigger('refresh-event', 'refresh', $data);

?>
```

I understand how to send a message like shown above but I don't know how to enable the refresh code. Has anyone used this sdk before and knows how?

**Alternatively**

Would anyone know any libraries or solutions on how to accomplish this task? Again, all I'm looking to do is refresh my web page dynamically to all my current viewers as and when I need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You callback function which is the second parameter to `refreshChannel.bind(...)` will run whenever a `'refresh-event'` is received on channel `'refreshing'`. The `$data` in your PHP gets passed to that function as well so you can send information with the event.

Your code to do this is almost spot on but it looks like you are forgetting to set the cluster in your javascript, so aren't successfully connecting. If your app is on the `'eu'` cluster you need to say so when you try to connect:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxx', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  encrypted: true
});
```

You should have been getting `"Could not find app by key xxx. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong cluster."` errors in the javascript console when you try to load the page.

edit: also on closer inspection your channel name and event are the wrong way around in your trigger call. It's

```
 $pusher->trigger('channel-name', 'event', $data);
```

edit 2: also in your javascript you're calling the channel `'refreshing'` and in your php you're calling it `'refresh'`. These have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your clients (pages that have the JavaScript code) make a **WebSocket** connection with pusher.com. You must trigger (= post data) to pusher api server via your php script and pusher will forward your data (event name + parameters) to all clients (connected sockets).

If you have your php code for example in index.php and access it via http it will send data to pusher and he will inform your clients.

Alternative to pusher.com you can create your own php WebSocket server.

Libs:

socketo.me and
socket.io

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to their system and not sure what you mean by Websocket connection. I dont see any tabs for that.When i click into my app it shows me Overview | Getting Started | App Keys | Stats | Debug | Error | Webhook | Push notification | Collab | App settings. Is there a tutorial somehwere on how to create this?

Comment: WebSocket is the technology behind pusher.com. WebSocket is just a protocol, providing full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection.  https://pusher.com/websockets

Comment: Open the page that you put the javascript code, then on a different tab open the the php page with pusher code and that should trigger refresh.  If your client page is php, then the php pusher code should not be on the same page else it will make an infinite loop.   

PHP API  > Pusher > PHP Client(s), 

OR

 PHP Client > PHP API > Pusher > PHP Client(s)